# How to check Microsoft PowerApps Portal version number?

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps

I wanted to verify if my PowerApps Portal app was at least version 9.3.2... I tried looking for the Portal version in the Portal Management and the Power Platform Admin Center without success.

Answer (score 3):

After some searching, I was able to view the PowerApps Portal version by using **https://<your_portal>.powerappsportals.com/_services/about**. Result should be similar to below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can go to https://make.powerapps.com/ which will take you to the homepage. Go to the Apps section(left-hand side), you can see all your apps listed. Go to your corresponding app and click on the 3 dots on the right side and from their go-to Details . It opens up a screen, now click on the Versions tab and there you can see all the versions of the app, the current version, and the live version.